# Hierarchical json to flat with parent ID

Tags: javascript, json

I have Hierarchical JSON and want to convert to flat JSON without parent child.

```
vm.str = [
    {
        "s_gid": 0,
        "title": "scholastic Master List 2016",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "templateId": "1",
                "s_gid": "10",
                "m_s_p_id": "1",
                "subject_group_name": "xxxxxxx",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "sname": "",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "Id": "2",
                        "templateId": "1",
                        "s_gid": "100",
                        "m_s_p_id": "0",
                        "subject_group_name": "abc",
                        "parent_id": "10",
                        "sname": "",
                        "nodes": [
                            {
                                "Id": "3",
                                "templateId": "1",
                                "s_gid": "1000",
                                "m_s_p_id": "0",
                                "subject_group_name": "efg",
                                "parent_id": "100",
                                "sname": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what to convert to new vm.str2 = [] as flat, all nodes at same level without nodes ... sub nodes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive function to return one array of objects

```js
var arr =[{"s_gid":0,"title":"scholastic Master List 2016","nodes":[{"Id":"1","templateId":"1","s_gid":"10","m_s_p_id":"1","subject_group_name":"xxxxxxx","parent_id":"1","sname":"","nodes":[{"Id":"2","templateId":"1","s_gid":"100","m_s_p_id":"0","subject_group_name":"abc","parent_id":"10","sname":"","nodes":[{"Id":"3","templateId":"1","s_gid":"1000","m_s_p_id":"0","subject_group_name":"efg","parent_id":"100","sname":""}]}]}]}]

function flatten(data) {
  var result = [];
  data.forEach(function(o) {
    var obj = {}
    for(var e in o) {
      (Array.isArray(o[e])) ? result.push(...flatten(o[e])) : obj[e] = o[e];
    }
    result.push(obj)
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(flatten(arr))
```

Comment: thanks. it working but I am getting 4 braket "[ [ [ [ " from starting

Comment: Make sure you write exactly same code, check this part again `result.push(...flatten(o[e]))` maybe you forgot `...` spread operator.

Comment: @fresher Instead of `...` spread operator you can also use `concat()` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1217/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` plus recursion for this task:

```
function getNodes(inputArr) {
    return inputArr.reduce(function (prev, value) {
        return prev.concat(
            [ value ],
            (value.nodes ? getNodes(value.nodes) : [])
        );
    }, []);
}
```

If you still want to remove `nodes`, you could either use `Array.prototype.map` or even `Array.prototype.each`:

```
output = output.map(function (value) {
    value.nodes = undefined;

    return value;
});
```

Comment: not able to use it. throwing error memo is not defined. can you print to console.

Comment: Made a mistake, should be ``prev`` instead of ``memo``.